# "gradlew build --rerun-tasks" didn't skip the excluded tests

Tags: unit-testing, gradle

I have some unit tests, I want to skip these tests in the gradle build.  ( I would like to use these tests to verify AWS setting)

Such as:

```
    @Test
    // Manual test to verify AWS setting
    // Make sure you log in correct QA account and export your credential to running environment
    // To run this test with console output:
    // ./gradlew test --tests AwsUtilTest.manualTest_verifyAssumeRole -i
    void manualTest_verifyAssumeRole() {
:
:

    }
```

Then in my build.gradle, I exclude those tests:

```
test {
    systemProperty "logging.config", "classpath:log4j2-local.yml"
    // Exclude manual test from pipeline
    // To run all manual tests in your local environment please use command : $./gradlew test --tests *.manualTest_*
    // Or you can specify a test to run in the above command line
    exclude '*.manualTest_*'
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
```

It works as I expected when I use "./gradlew clean build"
These tests were been skipped.

But when I run with command "gradlew build --rerun-tasks"
It failed on these tests:

```
> Task :test FAILED

AwsUtilTest > manualTest_verifyAssumeRole() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at AwsUtilTest.java:96
```

1. Why the tests were not excluded when build with "--rerun-tasks"?
2. How can I skip these tests when running "./gradlew build --rerun-tasks" (this command was config in the CI/CD pipeline"

Comment: I added "Disabled" annotation to disable these tests, it fixes the pipeline.
But in the local box, I have to manually remove this annotation to run these tests.
As an alternative solution, How can I still run the tests without removing the "Disabled" annotation?